# How do I save information from an GUI into a XML-file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I've created a program where users can input a few information and then can save everything into an xml file, or open it.

Before I setup that save and open thing on the bigger scale, I created a small test-run to find a solution. There are three textboxes where you can input your own information, two checkboxes and comboboxes where users can choose from a few options. I've created a open and save menu-strip-button but can't think of a way how to save all those information into a xml.file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileContent = string.Empty;
            var filePath = string.Empty;

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "XML-File | *.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Get the path of specified file
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    //Read the contents of the file into a stream
                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            //MessageBox.Show(fileContent, "File Content at path: " + filePath, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML-File | *.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    // Code to write the stream goes here.
                    myStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        /*private void validateUserEntry()
        {
            // Checks the value of the text.
            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 && textBox2.Text.Length == 0 && textBox3.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                // Initializes the variables to pass to the MessageBox.Show method.
                string message = " AAAAAAAAAAAAA";
                string caption = "Error Detected in Input";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                DialogResult result;

                // Displays the MessageBox.
                result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // Closes the parent form.
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know what the XML that represents "three textboxes where you can input your own information, two checkboxes and comboboxes where users can choose from a few options" would look like, or you don't know what the code to read and write such XML would look like?  It'd be helpful if you shared how that data is stored in your running application; is it stored in the GUI components themselves or do you have other data structures, too?

Comment: It's stored in the GUI components, but i can't figure how to program the read and write xml thing. I'm new to C# and still trying to get the hang of this programming language. maybe it'll help to say that i only worked with java previously.

Answer (score 0):

I use the library I wrote by using the [System.Xml.Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization?view=net-6.0) library in XML operations.
You can [download the source codes](https://github.com/GERD0GDU/XmlSerializer) or use them with the nuget package manager.

### [ioCode.Serialization](https://github.com/GERD0GDU/XmlSerializer)

C# types serialization library.
Serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents.

```
    PM> Install-Package ioCode.Serialization -Version 1.0.0
```

#### Classes

ioCode.Serialization library has two serialization classes

- **XmlSerializer<T>** Xml serialization object to serialize custom types
- **BinSerializer<T>** Bin serialization object for XML-based serialization of custom types. The serialized output file is encrypted.

#### XmlSerializer<T>

##### Write to file

```cs
  Product product = new Product();
  product.Name = "Product1";
  bool isSuccess = XmlSerializer<Product>.WriteFile(@"C:\users\[user]\documents\product.xml", product);
  MessageBox.Show(isSuccess ? "Success" : "Fail");
```

##### Read from file

```cs
  Product product = XmlSerializer<Product>.ReadFile(@"C:\users\[user]\documents\product.xml");
  MessageBox.Show((product != null) ? "Success" : "Fail");
```

#### BinSerializer<T>

##### Write to file

```cs
  Product product = new Product();
  product.Name = "Product1";
  bool isSuccess = BinSerializer<Product>.WriteFile(@"C:\users\[user]\documents\product.bin", "password123", product);
  MessageBox.Show(isSuccess ? "Success" : "Fail");
```

##### Read from file

```cs
  Product product = BinSerializer<Product>.ReadFile(@"C:\users\[user]\documents\product.bin", "password123");
  MessageBox.Show((product != null) ? "Success" : "Fail");
```

Comment: When giving an answer which promotes a library you maintain, it's worth disclosing that affiliation very clearly.